# EHCache Disable

Tags: ehcache

Is there a way to disable ehache externally using a property file? CacheManager.shutdown() doesnt seem to work? Actually we have 2 app with the same source code i require ehcache in one and not the other. one where i dont need cache is a webapp! Unable to figure to out yet how to go about this?

Comment: This may be better asked at serverfault.com (the StackOverflow sister site).

Answer (score 8):

There is a system property you can use for this:

```
net.sf.ehcache.disabled=true
```

Comment: but it means that I need to add it to the arguments of the java command (as -Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true). But I want it to have in my app.properties, so do not needed to change it externally in the tomcat startup options, etc.. how can I do that?

Comment: not sure - you might want to ask here: http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/forums/show/16.page

Comment: to clarify: this does not seem to work in spring's application.properties files

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and Alex Miller's solution helped me along. I do get the value from a properties file via this technique:

```
<!-- Enable/disable ehCache using property in config -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <!-- System.getProperties() -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.System" />
            <property name="targetMethod" value="getProperties" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <!-- The new Properties -->
        <util:properties>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.disabled">${net.sf.ehcache.disabled:false}</prop>

        </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following line

```
cache.getNativeCache().getCacheManager().getCacheManagerEventListenerRegistry().notifyCacheRemoved("properties");
```