# Disable / Switch off Ehcache3

Tags: caching, ehcache, jcache, jsr107, ehcache-3

Anybody knows how to switch off ehcache 3 in an application? (e.g. for testing purposes or fall back scenarios in production)

- For ehcache 2 this was possible with: `net.sf.ehcache.disabled=true`
  as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091251/ehcache-disable)
- How to disable all caches in ehcache3 (prefered via ehcache.xml)?

  - `org.ehcache.core.Ehcache` does not consist any disable functionallity
  - Is setting 
    `<heap unit="MB">0</heap>` in `ehcache.xml`  in a valid option?
  - I use JCache (aka JSR-107) with ehcache3 as implementation, maybe this give some more choices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing in Ehcache 3 at the moment. JCache does not have that option either.

You cannot size a resource to `0` so that's not an option either.

From here, two options:

- add a layer in your application doing the indirection and add the disabled support to that.
- Make a feature request on the [Ehcache users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ehcache-users) to get it considered for addition.